# Spring boot 3 and Spring security Pre Authorization

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I usually try to avoid using spring auth because it usually injects to many defaults that are extremely difficult to disable. But now I have a need to use JWT tokens. So I have created a security config but there is a Pre Authentication failure occurring that I can't firgure out how to disable: `Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access` Can anyone share with me how to disable the pre auth in a boot 3 app? Below is my current config

```
@Bean
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    return http.csrf { it.disable() }
        .authorizeHttpRequests { it.anyRequest().authenticated() }
        .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .build()
}

@Bean
fun authenticationProvider(): AuthenticationProvider {
    val authenticationProvider = JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder())
    return authenticationProvider
}

@Bean
fun jwtDecoder(): JwtDecoder {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaProperties.publicKey).build()
}

@Bean
fun jwtEncoder(): JwtEncoder {
    val jwk: JWK =
        RSAKey.Builder(rsaProperties.publicKey).privateKey(rsaProperties.privateKey).build()

    val jwks: JWKSource<SecurityContext> = ImmutableJWKSet(JWKSet(jwk))
    return NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks)
}
```

Debug Logs for Spring Security Web:

```
2024-02-14T13:58:20.238-08:00 DEBUG 5308 --- [tp1468039653-29] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy: Securing POST /v1/ds/123456789/register
2024-02-14T13:58:20.239-08:00 DEBUG 5308 --- [tp1468039653-29] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter: Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-02-14T13:58:20.239-08:00 DEBUG 5308 --- [tp1468039653-29] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2024-02-14T13:58:20.243-08:00 DEBUG 5308 --- [tp1468039653-29] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-02-14T13:58:20.244-08:00 DEBUG 5308 --- [tp1468039653-29] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-02-14T13:58:20.244-08:00 DEBUG 5308 --- [tp1468039653-29] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

Comment: please enable spring security DEBUG logs and edit your question to include the logs so that we can see what your request looks like and why it is refused.

Comment: Are referring to `logging.level.org.springframework.security.web=DEBUG`? I have that enabled but it does not provide much information.

Comment: Please update your question with those logs so we can look and see for ourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I believed that because the AuthenticationProvider was a JwtAuthenticationProvider, the guts of the jwt security filtering would be "provided" by that authentication provider, it is not. I updated my security config to have a jwtFilter along with the auth provider and now it is working. To resolve some circular references the encoder/decode beans from the question above were moved to a separate bean configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
  private val jwtDecoder: JwtDecoder,
  private val jwtfilter: JwtAuthFilter
) {

  @Bean
  @Throws(Exception::class)
  fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    return http.csrf { it.disable() }
        .authorizeHttpRequests { it.anyRequest().authenticated() }
        .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .addFilterBefore(jwtfilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        .build()
  }

  @Bean
  fun authenticationProvider(): AuthenticationProvider {
    val authenticationProvider = JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder)
    return authenticationProvider
  }
}
```

Here is the filter as well for those who want it, the jwtService referenced in the filter simply uses the NimbusJwtDecoder and NimbusJwtEncoder to do all the heavy lifting:

```
@Component
class JwtAuthFilter(private val jwtService: JwtService) : OncePerRequestFilter() {
val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

  override fun doFilterInternal(
    request: HttpServletRequest,
    response: HttpServletResponse,
    filterChain: FilterChain) {
    val authHeader: String = request.getHeader("Authorization") ?: throw InvalidJwtException("No JWT Header provided")
    var token: String? = null
    var cachingRequest: ContentCachingRequestWrapper? = null
    if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        token = authHeader.removePrefix("Bearer").trim()
    }
    val contentType = request.contentType
    if (contentType == null || !contentType.contains("multipart/form-data")) {
        // Wrap the request, so we can read the payload multiple times
        cachingRequest = ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request)
    }
    val payload = cachingRequest?.reader?.readText() ?: ""

    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication == null) {
        log.trace("Validating JWT token")
        jwtService.validateToken(token!!, payload)?.let {
            val authenticationToken = JwtAuthenticationToken(it, listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")))
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authenticationToken
        } ?: throw InvalidJwtException("Invalid JWT token provided")
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
  }
}
```